# How to write middleware like function in NodeJS using Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm just wondering what would be the best practice to do create a Middleware like function in ExpressJS using pure NodeJS and Typescript.

My first thought, I am thinking of using decorator function where once it succeeded it will launch next function, and so on.

Why would I create this?
I wanted to deploy functions to AWS, and using Express in AWS will waste computation. But I don't want the answer to be specific to AWS. Instead it will be nice to have the function good for any NodeJS environment.

I've looked to SO, and it seems that similar question haven't been asked. So it would be nice to validate my thoughts and create standard.

Comment: If you want to be able to run middlewares and routes but think Express is too heavy then check out Connect - https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect